# Problem optimization with symfony 6 / doctrine : too many querys

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

The project is develop with symfony 6.0.8.

I have 2 entitys : utilisateur (user) & compte_client (customer) - link by OneToOne relation because an user may be not a customer. A user can be : an employee, a partner or a customer. The foreign-key is in the customer table (compte_client -> utilisateur_id)

Here i want to recover informations from users who are customers too. I use the queryBuilder, i recover user's informations with this :

```
  $queryBuilder->andWhere('u.type_utilisateur = :val');
        $queryBuilder->setParameter('val', $type);
        $queryBuilder->join('u.compte_client','c')
            ->addSelect('c');
        $queryBuilder->orderBy('u.login', 'ASC');
        $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
        $results = $query->getResult();
        return $results;
```

I do a join to limit the number of querys but here, to recover 2 user's datas, it realized 7 querys.
If I delete the join request, it realise 3 querys, but i think it can be reduce to 1 query (as i see in online courses - that used join request too).

I tried to add some attributs on my entites like "fetch:EAGER" or "fetch:EXTRA_LAZY" but it's ineffective.

Before all of it, I had similar problem to recover data's from users that aren't customers. When i checked querys realized by doctrine for loading only users who are employee, their was so many useless querys to customer's table despite of I didn't try to recover any customer's information, and their was no result expected. To reduce the number of query's i had to add a join request like that :

```
 $queryBuilder
            ->Where('u.type_utilisateur LIKE :type')
            ->setParameter('type', 'Entreprise%') 
            ->leftjoin('u.compte_client','c')
                ->addSelect('c')
            ->orderBy('u.login', 'ASC');
        $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
        $results = $query->getResult();
        return results;
```

This, reduce query at only 1.

So is there some good pratice to optimize the number of querys generat by doctrine ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to think of Doctrine OneToOne as a form of inheritance: the inverse side "inherits" the owning side's properties (reminder: [The owning side of a OneToOne association is the entity with the table containing the foreign key](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#bidirectional-associations)) so when you fetch the inverse side Doctrine always fetches the owning side.

That means the good practice here would be to change the owning side as it makes more sense for `customer` to inherit from `user`.